# How to design domain driven design application service for aggregate?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am new at domain driven design, so I want to ask about using application service for aggregate root.

I have an aggregate root.

```
public class Product: AggreagateRoot{
    publis int Id {get; set;}
    publis string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Types> Types {get; set;}
}
```

The comments and Types are related with Product. So a Comment or a Type doesn't mean anything by itself.

So I am creating an application service for product.

```
public class ProductService {

    public Product Create(ProductCommand command){
        .....
        ...
    }

    public Product Update(ProductCommand command){
        .....
        ...
    }

}
```

Should I add methods for create and update Comments and Types in ProductService like following?

```
public class ProductService {

    public Product Create(ProductCommand command){
        .....
        ...
    }

    public Product Update(ProductCommand command){
        .....
        ...
    }

    public Comment Create(CommantCommand command){
        var product = _context.Product.Find(command.ProductId);

        product.Comments.add(new Comment(command.message));

        _context.SaveChanges();
        .....
        ...
    }

    public Comment Update(CommantCommand command){
        var comment = _context.Comments.Find(command.Id);

        comment.message = command.message;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        .....
        ...
    }       
}
```

Or Should I create seperate services for Comment and Types?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product: AggreagateRoot{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Types> Types {get; set;}
}
```

This pattern, as shown, is usually referred to as an [anemic domain model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), which is generally considered to be an anti-pattern.  The piece that is missing is that the behaviors, which is to say the logic that describes how this data structure evolves over time, live in your application service code, rather than being in the domain model.

In other words, what you have implemented here is a dumb bag of data.

What we normally do instead is write the code so that the domain behaviors are in the domain entities.  The code in the application layer just invokes the domain model code.  For example:

```
Create(CommantCommand command){
    var product = _context.Product.Find(command.ProductId);

    product.AddComment(command.message));

    _context.SaveChanges();
    .....
    ...
```

> Should I create seperate services for Comment and Types?

Application components should only talk to aggregate roots.  That's part of the point of having roots.  Therefore, if we assume that Comments and Types belong in one aggregate, then no, there shouldn't be separate services for them.

If multiple products share the *same* Type, then it may make sense to make Type its own aggregate.